# How to trigger horizontal scroll on mouse wheel in typescript

Tags: typescript, scroll

I tried to trigger horizontal scroll on mouse wheel. However, I think that typescript doesn't allow to update the value of deltaX. Not sure if anyone has an idea for this situation. This my code:

```
 `document.querySelector('#tab-primary-wrapper .inner-wrapper').addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e: WheelEvent) {
            this.deltaX -= (e.deltaY);
            e.preventDefault();
        },
`
```

Comment: its a javsacript question, no angular nor typescript specific subject

Comment: I think typescript define property as readonly, so I cannot change the value.

Comment: Typescript has zero runtime impact

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand your code, but where does the deltaX come from, dont you have an ordinary dom element referenced by `this`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try setting [scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) of your element:

```
document.querySelector('#tab-primary-wrapper .inner-wrapper').addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e: WheelEvent) {
            this.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```