# Mousewheel function returning error on svelte

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-component

i'd like to know why this code

```
<div class="home" on:mousewheel="{e=>handleScroll(e)}"></div>
```

is returning the following error

> Type '{ class: string; onmousewheel: (e: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLProps'.
> Property 'onmousewheel' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps'.

It is just for curiosity because it works perfectly even with the error.

Ps. I'm using TypeScript

Comment: I am not familiar with typescript, but I think you need to do it something like that: `<div class="home" onmousewheel="{e: WheelEvent=>handleScroll(e)}"></div>` see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55573846/4593433 Also there is a typo: `on:mousewheel`, but I suppose its not in your real code if it works already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mousewheel event is [deprecated according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event) and won't work in Firefox. Because it's non-standard, it is not included in the [JSX typings](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/packages/svelte2tsx/svelte-jsx.d.ts) used by Svelte.

It would be better to use the standard [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event), which replaced mousewheel. If you really want to use the event, you can [enhance the Svelte typings](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-using-an-attributeevent-on-a-dom-element-and-it-throws-a-type-error) in a separate file:

```
// additional-svelte-jsx.d.ts
declare namespace svelte.JSX {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
        onmousewheel?: (event: any) => any;
    }
}
```

Comment: The namespace has changed from `svelte.JSX` to `svelteHTML` now.

https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-getting-deprecation-warnings-for-sveltejsx--i-want-to-migrate-to-the-new-typings

Answer (score 1):

I believe the event you are looking for is [onwheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onwheel) which would translate to `on:wheel` in Svelte.

Alternatively, if you're only interested in the mouse wheel events for scrolling purposes, the correct event would be [onscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onscroll) (`on:scroll` in Svelte).